# certain use of the bitwise operator unclear

Tags: c++-cli, clr

why is the bitwise operator before variable name when declaring this

```
Ping ^pingSender = gcnew Ping;
```

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Comment: This is not XOR it is .NET based C++, CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about this code??

```
Ping ^ pingSender = gcnew Ping;

// When the PingCompleted event is raised, 
// the PingCompletedCallback method is called.
pingSender->PingCompleted += gcnew PingCompletedEventHandler( PingCompletedCallback );
```

Here this implies instance of ping class will be created  from  System.Net.NetworkInformation::Ping. Simply, this is not XOR operation but syntax of declaring object of managed type in microsoft implementation of C++ for .NET.

Comment: Thank you all.
Figured it out now.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, `^` is not the bitwise XOR; it declares `pingSender` to be a reference to the managed type (a type native to .NET) `Ping`.

I assume you are familiar with the basics of C# and regular, non-managed C++.

This line of code equals

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping();
```

in C#, and in case `Ping` was a non-managed C++ class,

```
Ping* pingSender = new Ping;
```

in C++. As you can see, `^` has another meaning when used in a declaration, just as `*` does for unmanaged types in C/C++.

Comment: Note that the code **is not C++**, but a Microsoft language that happens to be an extension of C++.